# In Access VBA 2010: If x + y + z > 100 unclear

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
Dim A_Mix, B_Mix, C_Mix As Double

If Forms![Mischung].[mix1].Value Then
    A_Mix = Forms![Mischung].[subfrm_mix1].Form.[mix1].Value
Else
    A_Mix = 0
End If

If Forms![Mischung].[mix2].Value Then
    B_Mix = Forms![Mischung].[subfrm_mix2].Form.[mix1].Value
Else
    B_Mix = 0
End If

If Forms![Mischung].[mix3].Value Then
    C_Mix = Forms![Mischung].[subfrm_mix3].Form.[mix1].Value
Else
    C_Mix = 0
End If

If (A_Mix + B_Mix + C_Mix) > 100 Then
    MsgBox A_Mix & " + " & B_Mix & " + " & C_Mix & " > 100 Ungültig!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
```

The above vba code is used to decide how much of a specific fuel will be mixed. I want to check that the sum of all amounts (A_Mix, B_Mix, C_mix) does not exceed 100.

If for instance A_Mix=50 and B_Mix=50 and C_Mix=0,  then (A_Mix + B_Mix + C_Mix) > 100 evaluates True and the Popup is shown with a Text like 50 + 50 + 0 > 100

This seems to happen whenever I choose an A,B or C, which sums up to 100.

Except when I choose only one mixand, then vba passes the If without showing the msgbox.

I dont get VBA's logic here, and think I did some erroneous thinking.
Can anybody shed some light onto this matter?

Comment: What do you see when you single-step through your code? (F9 to set a breakpoint, F8 to step through the code.)

Comment: @Heinzi, lot of thanks for your effort, but this has been resolved already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim A_Mix As Double
Dim B_Mix As Double
Dim C_Mix As Double

If Nz(Forms![Mischung].[mix1].Value, 0) > 0 Then
    A_Mix = Forms![Mischung].[subfrm_mix1].Form.[mix1].Value
End If

If Nz(Forms![Mischung].[mix2].Value, 0) > 0 Then
    B_Mix = Forms![Mischung].[subfrm_mix2].Form.[mix1].Value
End If

If Nz(Forms![Mischung].[mix3].Value, 0) > 0 Then
    C_Mix = Forms![Mischung].[subfrm_mix3].Form.[mix1].Value
End If

If (A_Mix + B_Mix + C_Mix) > 100 Then
    MsgBox A_Mix & " + " & B_Mix & " + " & C_Mix & " > 100 Ungültig!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: -1 for no explanation of dimming several things per line, but 
+2 for the Nz(val, val), which simplified my code at many lines :)

Comment: You could shorten each of those `If...End If` blocks to just `A_Mix = Nz(Forms![Mischung].[subfrm_mix1].Form.[mix1].Value, 0)`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook: That's not the same logic as the original code.

Comment: I don't see why it isn't @Gustav.  If the sum of the three text boxes is greater than 100..... ok, just see what you meant. - check the value of `Forms![Mischung].[mix1].Value` and add `Forms![Mischung].[subfrm_mix1].Form.[mix1].Value`.  My bad - I'll just go and slink off into a corner.

Answer (score 0):

I found the not so obvious culprit: the first line

```
Dim A_Mix, B_Mix, C_Mix As Double
```

Only C_Mix gets Dimmed as Double, while the prepending A_/B_Mix are dimmed as something else (Variant?)

This is a caveat IMHO. Is there a way to Dim many per line, that works?

from https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/7ee5a7s1.aspx

```
Dim a, b, c As Single, x, y As Double, i As Integer
' a, b, and c are all Single; x and y are both Double
```

Doesnt work in my case?

Comment: The link you posted is for VB.NET. `Dim` statements in VBA work differently: `Dim a As Single, b As Single, ...`

Comment: p.s. Yes, in your first example `A_Mix` and `B_Mix` will be of type `Variant`.

Comment: @Gord Thompson, thank you very much for the clarification.